# What is the word for when someone is saying the same thing as you, but thinks you are disagreeing?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, I remember it was a single word that had this sort of definition. It also had a neutral conotation to it. I came across the word in a video or a game I can't quite remember.

I already looked at the answers posted on cpu2007's question asking almost the same thing, but the word I was looking for was not there.

If it were used in a sentence it would go like this:

> Just *blank* is all, I am not disagreeing with you.

Comment: You could fit literally anything in "just *blank* is all", and it could be an adjective, noun, participle, or maybe even adverb - it's not terribly helpful. There are various words and phrases like *misapprehension*, *crossed wires* and *cross purposes* but I've no idea if they fit.

Comment: The question has been asked before, and an answer (vehement / violent agreement) given. The correct procedure to ask for further answers to the same question is to offer a bonus ... but admittedly, this only works when you have sufficient rep points.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a single word, but a common way to describe this situation is that you and the other party are in *[violent agreement](https://wiki.c2.com/?ViolentAgreement)*.

> **Violent Agreement**
>
> Two people are arguing about something. It is clear to everyone else
> at the meeting that the two hold the same point.